# Surprisingly, I got student finance - How could I approach management?

Tags: salary, resignation, negotiation, training

Got myself into quite a unique situation & would appreciate some different perspectives on my options.

**My Situation**

I work full-time for a small aerospace company working as an Electronic Engineer, **Company X** in the UK. I don't particularly like my job at Company X, but it was a good offer and allowed me to re-locate across the country last year.

I was actually under qualified for the role, but the company agreed to hire me with a lower salary & send me to University on a part-time course for a degree. There was one string attached - I work back half the time I am out of office. This equated to 2hrs per week last year and 4hrs per week this year.

The course is 1-day per week and I am currently in year 2 of 3.5.

I work an extra hour every day, except my university day which is slightly shorter but more taxing.

**The Pickle**

I applied for government student finance during a period of illness at the start of this year. At the time, I was worried that I could not return to work but wanted to continue studying.

Although I completed the application, I mistakenly believed I had not been accepted as they asked for extra information to support my application (this was for additional funding).

As of today, I have been paid a maintenance payment of nearly £1000 and this years course fees or £6000 have been paid. The interest rate is 5.4% and is taken pre-tax once I begin earning above ~£25k (which I am).

Company X are fully expecting to have to pay £6k this year for my study.

I would like to leave Company X & take time out to focus on my studies and promising side-business. I don't enjoy the work at Company X and the increase in time I have to make up is quite draining. I'm the last out of the building every day & hit rush hour traffic both ways. I'm so tired in the evenings that I struggle to study & my sleep is poor from the stress. I am still on medication from my illness earlier in the year.

**Your considered thoughts on how I could come to a decision would be appreciated.**

**edit:** I would be contractually obliged to repay course fees for the year in which I leave. However, they won't apply this year due to the finance i.e. I have an opportunity to leave which has not been available before now.

Comment: +1 to what Joe said. You do not struggle onwards if health issues are involved

Comment: Thank you for the concern. My doctors allowed me to return to work a few months ago & I am doing much better. I do worry that my health could decline again in future though, if I burn out.

Comment: I think this is a good question (hence my answer), but as a warning: your question is attracting close votes since it's asking for a specific choice. It may help to edit it and ask __how__ to make your choice instead of __which__ choice to make.

Comment: @PlayerOne Thanks for the heads up - I have removed the options and left it broader.

Answer (score 7):

**Don't over-commit.** It won't help you, or your current employer. It will only burn you out.

A great business owner I once worked for gave me some amazing advice, which is self evident when you think about it: *"Don't ever risk **your** health for **my** money"*.

Focus on growing yourself, and don't worry about the company you currently work for. They will be fine with or without you. You owe them nothing beyond what you've contractually agreed to (including the terms under which you are able to leave).

Don't worry about how much it will cost them (and frankly £6k is nothing for a company, even though I know it seems like a lot).

We can't do the maths on what is financially better for you - we don't have all the information required to do that. Regardless, my opinion is that what's financially better right now isn't necessarily the best choice, and certainly not in the long term.

You need to be mentally healthy for both your personal *and* financial future.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have definitely over committed with my day-job, social life, side business & studying. I have an opportunity to cut the most stressful part (my day job) and that is what I am considering - please refer to my edit. However, a bird in the hand... etc.

Comment: @MIL-SPEC I hear you, I understand your dilmemma, and I'm answering based on my own experience :) Prioritise yourself and your family first, your education second and your long-term employment will happen.

Comment: I appreciate your insight. I will discuss this with my family tonight.